# Unable to reach port of rootless docker container from host

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, rootless

I've just installed [rootless docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) on my machine (Ubuntu 20.04.5, Docker 20.10.21) and tried to run jupyter inside it and access the jupyter server from the host.

I've run the container with/without `--net=host` and jupyter with/without `--ip=0.0.0.0`, but neither lets me access the server from outside the container.

Edit: so I managed to run the container with an explicit port mapping (i.e. `-p 8888:8888`) and access the jupyter server on that port (running it with the `--ip 0.0.0.0` option) from the host machine. A bit less usable, but at least it works at all.